# Show list of Facebook friends for invite to rails app? omniauth-facebook and koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I want to display a div showing the current.user's facebook friends so they can invite them to join my new rails website. How do I display that info with the invite? I got permission to view friends and post to page but not sure how to implement. Thanks!

omniauth.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
 $('body').prepend('<div id="fb-root"></div>')

 $.ajax
  url: "#{window.location.protocol}//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"
  dataType: 'script'
  cache: true


window.fbAsyncInit = ->
FB.init(appId: 'APP_ID', cookie: true)

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
 if (response.status === 'connected') {
  FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
    if (response && response.data)({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'Join me on my new site!'
  }, requestCallback);
 } else {
      console.log('Something goes wrong', response);
   }
  });
 }
});
```

modal window

```
<!-- fb modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="fbfriends" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Invite your friends!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      list_of_facbook_friends
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

user.rb

```
def friend_invite
 @friends = current_user.facebook.get_connections("me", "friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(small)")   
end
```